# Iterating through a data.table using aggregation

Tags: r, data.table

My `data.table` is like:

```
AccountNo    SubscriptionStart     SubscriptionEnd
11111        2010-10-12            2011-10-11
11112        2009-03-08            2010-03-08
11112        2010-03-08            2011-03-08
11112        2012-03-08            2013-03-08
11113        2011-08-21            2012-08-21
```

All I would like to achieve is adding a new column that flags accounts that got renewed later.

In other words: GotRenewed is TRUE if SubscriptionEnd <= max(SubscritionStart) within the subset defined by AccountNo. In this example it would be like:

```
AccountNo    SubscriptionStart     SubscriptionEnd    GotRenewed
11111        2010-10-12            2011-10-11         0
11112        2009-03-08            2010-03-07         1
11112        2010-03-08            2011-03-07         1
11112        2012-03-08            2013-03-07         0
11113        2011-08-21            2012-08-21         0
```

How could I achieve this? I appreciate your help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt[,GotRenewed := SubscriptionEnd <= max(SubscriptionStart), by=AccountNo]

   AccountNo SubscriptionStart SubscriptionEnd GotRenewed
1:     11111        2010-10-12      2011-10-11      FALSE
2:     11112        2009-03-08      2010-03-08       TRUE
3:     11112        2010-03-08      2011-03-08       TRUE
4:     11112        2012-03-08      2013-03-08      FALSE
5:     11113        2011-08-21      2012-08-21      FALSE
```

Use `as.numeric` if you really need 0/1.